# removing an element from array

Tags: javascript

```
rowData = [];

alert(rowData[0]);
```

gives me `[Ti.UI.TableViewRow]`

Now how can i remove this element... i have been using rowData.splice(), but i have no idea on what to pass to remove it.

Thanks

Comment: Note that removing it from the array won't remove it from the document, for this you need something like `rowData[0].style.display = "none";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you present `rowData` should be empty, so `rowData[0]` should be `undefined`. I suppose something is pushed to `rowData` in between? Anyway, there are several ways to remove elements from arrays:

- You can remove all elements at once
  from an array using `rowData.length =
  0`.
- If you want to remove 1 element, use
  the `Array.splice` method. E.g.
  removing the first element:
  `rowData.splice(0,1)` (means *remove
  1 element of rowData starting from
  element 0 (the first element)*.
- If it's only the first element you
  want to remove you could also use the
  `shift` method: `rowData.shift()`.
- The last method you can use is
  `slice`: `rowData = rowData.slice(1)`
  (means: *give me all elements from
  rowData starting at the first element and
  assign the result to `rowData`*), 
  or `rowData.slice(1,4)` (means: 
  *give me all elements from
  rowData starting at the first element,
  ending at the fourth element, and
  assign the result to `rowData`*).

Answer (score 3):

try `rowData.splice(0, 1);` the first argument indicates the index of item to be removed, the second indicates how many items should be removed

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the element(s) entirely, [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) will return a new array with the member(s) removed.

You can also use the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/operators/special_operators/delete_operator) operator, but this won't affect the `Array` size and the member will be `undefined`. This is will also make it non enumerable.